# One sensor as output?

Tags: java, android, xml

i have this method

```
public String getSensor() {

    SensorManager mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

    String sensoriV ="";   

    List<Sensor> mList = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

    for (int i = 1; i < mList.size(); i++) {

    sensoriV =  "\n" + mList.get(i).getName() ;



    }

    return sensoriV;

    }
```

In an other method (same Activity Class) i have this code

```
String[] sensori = { ""+sensor };
```

Why when I open the application I only have one sensor as outpout on my Nexus? Where is the error and how can I fix

Comment: what is `sensor` in mentioned in last line `{ ""+sensor }` ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a `+` in the following line:

```
sensoriV = "\n" + mList.get(i).getName() ;
```

Should be:

```
sensoriV += "\n" + mList.get(i).getName() ;
```

And your for loop should start at `int i = 0`.

You're actually getting all the right info. It's just semantic errors in your String concatenation routine.

Comment: Okay, it work. Many thanks. Is there a way to have more information on sensors?

Comment: If you mean "more information" as in data from the sensors, then yeah, definitely. Here's the place to start: [Sensors Overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html). If you mean manufacturer info or hardware specs, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

1.may be there is only one Sensor
2.may be your should init i=0, not start loop from i=1
3.the information you display is not enough

Comment: 1. I do not think the Nexus 4 has only one sensor (gyroscope).
2. I tried to put int = 0 but the result is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
...
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

List<Sensor> deviceSensors = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

System.out.println(deviceSensors.size());//It will print the No of sensor availbale.

for(int i=0; i<deviceSensors.size(); i++) {

             System.out.println(deviceSensors.get(i).getName());

     }
```